# Data Explorer - top 50 askers

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to write a query to see who are the Top 50 biggest "askers" (ask the most questions) on StackOverflow, and how many questions they've asked.  My best attempt (which throws an error), which I know is wrong, is:

```
SELECT
    Users.Id, sum(Posts.Id)
FROM
    Users u
    INNER JOIN
    Posts p

    ON
    u.Id = p.Id
WHERE
    max(p)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why invent the wheel twice?! Use [an existing query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/33130/top-askers-with-score)

```
SELECT TOP 50
  OwnerUserId as [User Link],
  COUNT(*) as PostCount,
  SUM(Score) as TotalScore
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId=1 AND OwnerUserId != 1
GROUP BY OwnerUserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: "Why invent the wheel twice?" So that we can have two wheels and encourage competition in the market and drive innovation.